# Create adminhtml block in cron

Tags: adminhtml, blocks, cron

I am running a cron that will email the products sold report daily.
The issue I am having is that when I create the blocks in the cron model, the grid template attempts to load from frontend design path:

CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/report/grid.phtml

The path for the template should be: adminhtml/default/default/template/report/grid.phtml

My code to build the block is:

```
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$block = $layout->createBlock('adminhtml/report_product_sold');
$grid = $block->getChild('grid');
$html = $grid->toHtml();
```

I am sure I am just missing something obvious, but cannot fathom what at this point :(

Comment: Are you using .modman/symlinks for that?

Comment: No. This is a standard module with cron setup via config.xml. located under app/code/local

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with this right above your code, works for me

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
```